# Android ontouchlistener at rotated view

Tags: android, view, rotation, ontouchlistener

would like to get some advise for my problem. Currently I have a view which has an ontouchlistener on it. Then the view will rotate follow finger movement. When ACTION_UP, the view will be in a new position. Then, if I touch again on the view(which is in the new position), it cant detect the touch down. If I touch on the old position, it can detect the touch. This made me feel that the ontouchlistener is still stick with the old area which is the initial position of the view. When the view is rotated and the area for the touch listener suppose is at different area, but the on touchlistener still stick with old area.Any advise to overcome this issue.Thanks in advanced.

```
    _____
   |  0  |  Initial view and the 0 is the touch point, it can be touched and
   |     |  rotate follow finger movement.
   |     |
   |_____|


   _________
  |         |  After I rotate clockwise, then I touch on the 0 again, it cant detect
  |        0|  my touch.
  |_________|


       1
   _________
  |         |  However, if I touch on the 1, which is the first point that I touched, it
  |        0|  can detect my touch.
  |_________|



  private double mCurrAngle = 0;
  private double mPrevAngle = 0;
  ImageView alarm_hand;

private class touchEvent implements OnTouchListener{

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final float xc = alarm_hand.getWidth() / 2;
        final float yc = alarm_hand.getHeight() / 2;

        final float x = event.getX();
        final float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            Log.d("test", "ACTION_DOWN");
                alarm_hand.clearAnimation();
                mCurrAngle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(x - xc, yc - y));
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                mPrevAngle = mCurrAngle;
                mCurrAngle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(x - xc, yc - y));
                animate(mPrevAngle, mCurrAngle, 0);
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP : {

            break;
        }
        }

        return true;
    }

}

private void animate(double fromDegrees, double toDegrees, long durationMillis) {
    final RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation((float) fromDegrees, (float) toDegrees,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotate.setDuration(durationMillis);
    rotate.setFillEnabled(true);
    rotate.setFillAfter(true);
    alarm_hand.startAnimation(rotate);
}

    private void rotate(double angle ){
      Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
      alarm_hand.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);   //required
      matrix.postRotate((float) angle, alarm_hand.getDrawable().getBounds().width()/2,   alarm_hand.getDrawable().getBounds().height()/2);
      alarm_hand.setImageMatrix(matrix);
  }
```

//Update

I tried to rotate using Matrix which is the rotate() function instead of using RotateAnimation, but the image does not rotate in the way I wanted. The pic below are the screen shot(the blue colour image is the alarm_hand imageview). It seems like the bound are still there. The imageview are set to wrap_content for both width and height. Do the rotate function is wrong? Please guide me if possible. Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: How do you rotate your view? Show code.

Comment: Added the code for reference

Comment: dont use RotateAnimation, use ImageView.getImageMatrix and transform that Matrix

Comment: what happens if you remove and readd the touchlistener after the rotation? i think this will work than

Comment: I try to remove the touchlistener where I set alarm_hand.setOnTouchListener(null); and then set touchlistener again but it does not work too.